# How to set the python path in Centos Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I am new to python and trying to install it on my centos  server . By default there was 2.6 version which I deleted and installed the new version 2.7.x ...

But I am facing problem . when I type the below command it gives me the message

```
python --version
-bash: python: command not found
```

I can see that python is installed in /usr/local/bin .. How can I set the path so I may run the above command and it gives me the correct version..

Please help

Comment: Note that removing the installed Python can cause all sorts of problems for system stuff that expects to be able to use that Python. It's generally _much_ safer to install a new Python version separately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add python to your `$PATH` environment variable. You can use the following command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python
```

This will append the `/usr/local/bin/python` to the existing `$PATH`. It is necessary to reopen the shell window afterwards.